# How to run Phonegap 3.1 on Windows with Android

Tags: android, cordova, project

I spent hours with the official phonegap how to and also with the old phonegap tutorials in the net. I think you couldn't write a tutorial more complicated. And the old ones are worthless because everything changed in version 3.0. I spent hours to get a project running, but it is very easy. Therefore read the tutorial which I will post as an anser to that question.

Comment: Tutorial from my dropbox --> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13223652/PhoneGap%20on%20Windows%20How%20by%20Colin%20Baumann.docx

will post the answer correctly later (I have to wait 8hours)

Comment: PDF if you don't have word --> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13223652/PhoneGap%20on%20Windows%20How%20by%20Colin%20Baumann.pdf

Comment: You may want to read [about SO](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: Hi Rajesh, I'm aware that this is not the main idea of SO, but I still think it's better to post a tutorial here in that way instead of other guys wasting hours like I did...

Comment: This is not a question........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhoneGap on Windows How-to as of 27.11.2013

1. Download and install node.js from (http://nodejs.org/ )
2. Go to start, enter cmd (run as admin).
3. Enter npm install -g phonegap and press enter
4. Phonegap CLI on top of cordova CLI is now installed, test it by entering phonegap help in the command prompt.
5. phonegap create C:\Users\Colin\Desktop\HSR\Android\PhoneGap_Shizzle\momo "com.momo.www" "momo"
6. cd momo
7. VERY IMPORTANT! Start, programs, android, sdk (start as admin).
8. Update Everything if needed, restart, update again etc. If you are up to date. Go to to next step.
9. Deinstall all old android versions (and everything you don’t need), old versions can lead to phonegap not being able to build etc.
10. Install the latest (maybe only the latest) android version.
11. Make sure you are absolutely up to date, only have the latest version plus platform and sdk tools.
12. If you work with eclipse later (which I recommend) open eclipse now and install the updates there as well (if you get prompted, otherwhise you are ok).
13. Go to Start, programs, android, avd. Delete all the old emulators, and make a new one with the lates android version, just use 768mb ram and make sure you can start it. (very important!!!)
14. Now we can finally go back to the command prompt. Enter phonegap install android. (if that fails enter cordova platform add android).
15. If the previos step succeded without errors. Start the emulator. Once it is started, enter in the command prompt phonegap run android
16. It takes a while, but after a while your app should then run in the emulator or your phone.
17. If that didn’t work or you want to work in eclipse anyways, open eclipse, new other, android project with existing code, as root of the project enter the path of your created project from the command prompt (for me it was C:\Users\Colin\Desktop\HSR\Android\PhoneGap_Shizzle\momo), and finish.
18. Right Click on all other projects in your work space and close/unload them. Then on the bottom of eclipse open the problem/error view and try to fix problems. (most of the time it helps if you go to project>clean … also make sure you have project build on automatic. Then try to run the project out of eclipse.
19. Cheers have fun.

PS: Worked for me, if you have any questions, just ask. Btw, it was quite late when I wrote that tutorial, that's the reason for all the typos and the weird language.

Regards Colin

Comment: By the way, for everyone struggling with Phonegap, try this --> http://www.mosync.com/. It's the easiest way to get JS code running on different devices. Installation is a normal installer, just pressing next and ok, provides you with an eclipse IDE and you don't have to configure anything! Deployment of the first app is super easy, took me not more than 3 minutes after the installation. Cheers

Comment: Error While Executing command 'ant'... on step # 14